# Find max-number div by three to be formed by array elements

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

> Given an array of non-negative integers, find the largest multiple of 3 that can be formed from array elements.
>
> For example, if the input array is {8, 1, 9}, the output should be "9 8 1", and if the input array is {8, 1, 7, 6, 0}, output should be "8 7 6 0".

Looking for code-review, best-practices and optimizations.

```
public final class DivThree {

    private DivThree() {}
    
    public static int divThree(int[] a) {
        final Queue<Integer> queue0 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // if num % 3 == 0, store num in queue0.
        final Queue<Integer> queue1 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // if num % 3 == 1, store num in queue1.
        final Queue<Integer> queue2 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // if num % 3 == 2, store num in queue2.
        
        Arrays.sort(a);

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum = sum  + a[i];
            
            int remainder = a[i] % 3;
            
            if (remainder == 0) {
                queue0.add(a[i]);
            } else  if (remainder == 1) {
                queue1.add(a[i]);
            } else {
                queue2.add(a[i]);
            }
        } 
        
        if (sum % 3 == 1) {
            if (!queue1.isEmpty()) {
                queue1.remove();
            } else {
                if (!queue2.isEmpty()) {
                    queue2.remove();
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (!queue2.isEmpty()) {
                    queue2.remove();
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        } else if (sum % 3 == 2) {
            if (!queue2.isEmpty()) {
                queue2.remove();
            } else {
                if (!queue1.isEmpty()) {
                    queue1.remove();
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (!queue1.isEmpty()) {
                    queue1.remove();
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.addAll(queue0);
        list.addAll(queue1);
        list.addAll(queue2);
   
        Collections.sort(list);
        
        int result = 0;
        int pow = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result = result  + pow * list.get(i);
            pow = pow * 10;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}

public class DivThreeTest {
    
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        assertEquals(432, DivThree.divThree(a1));
    }

    
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        int a2[] = {8, 1, 7, 6, 0};
        assertEquals(8760, DivThree.divThree(a2));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I got to this question as a result of inadvertedly leaving "Ruby" out of my search string, but before departing I cannot resist:
for `1.upto(a.size).flat_map { |n| a.permutation(n).map { |e| [e, e.map(&:to_s).join.to_i] } }.select { |_,n| n%3 == 0 }.max_by(&:last).first.map(&:to_s).join(' ') #=> "8 7 6 0"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland cute but definitely fails the "code review, best practices, and optimizations" test.

Answer (score 6):

> For example, if the input array is {8, 1, 9}, the output should be “9 8 1″

So, let's say that the input array is `{ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 }`, what should the output be then? At first I expected it to be `"4 8 15 16 23 42"`, but then @Marc-Andre made me realize that in fact, that's not the case. I misunderstood the question at first.

Although not explicitly written, all the numbers in the array are required to be less than 10. I strongly suggest you add a check in your loop: (which btw can be written as for-each instead, which also applies to your last loop for looping through the list)

```
for (int i : a) {
    sum = sum  + i;

    if (i >= 10) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("All numbers must be less than 10.");
    }

    int remainder = a % 3;
    ...
}
```

I have to say though that the example you give is a bit weird, as your example output is a string separated by space. The question though is about *what number can be formed*, which don't speak anything about string at all.

In addition to this, you also suffer from a case of severe code-duplication. This can be treated easily with the medicine of *extracting method*. This extracted method also deserves a little simplification as I really don't like that you're doing `isEmpty-remove-isEmpty-remove`, why not just check if `size > 2` in the first place? (Alright, size *can* be a costly operation compared to `isEmpty` for some queue implementations, but `LinkedList` is not one of those - at least not anymore).

```
private static boolean removeOneOrTwo(Queue<?> removeOneFrom, Queue<?> removeTwoFrom) {
    if (!removeOneFrom.isEmpty()) {
        removeOneFrom.remove();
    } else if (removeTwoFrom.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    } else {
        removeTwoFrom.remove();
        removeTwoFrom.remove();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that here I actually use `Queue<?>`, more or less just for the fun of it but mostly for the reason that for this method, it doesn't need to know what kind of `Queue` we're dealing with. It only needs to be able to know the size of it and remove items.

By doing this simple method extraction, we've reduced your original method a bit:

```
if (sum % 3 == 1) {
    if (!removeOneOrTwo(queue1, queue2)) {
        return -1;
    }
} else if (sum % 3 == 2) {
    if (!removeOneOrTwo(queue2, queue1)) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Although now that I'm dealing with that code anyway, I have to add: **`return -1;` smells.** -1 is a special return value for "no possible combination found". In this case I would find `0` a better choice of return value for that, as that would correspond to an empty array (and is a multiple of 3). Either that, or throw an exception. In this case, I would find returning zero perfectly reasonable.

Comment: `but then I realized that in fact` No no no, I made you realize that :P

Comment: @Marc-Andre Correct, credit where credit's due! Better?

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in your algorithm. Writing only two tests for your algorithm is not enough. Try this test case :

```
@Test
public void testWithAnArraySize10() {
    int bigArray[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    assertEquals(9876543210L, DivThree.divThree(bigArray));
}
```

So when your array have a size of more than 9, things is beginning to go wrong. The problem is not about the output because you got the good result (`list = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}`, but your simple `for` loop break the things.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result = result  + pow * list.get(i);
        pow = pow * 10;
    }
```

At the tenth element, `pow` was `1410065408` which is obviously wrong.

The real question is : Is `{9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}` a valid input ? I can't say since your definition of the problem is missing some precisions. On the other side if you would output an array like @Simon said, this would not be a problem (and you would have one less loop).